# Midnight commander: screen list

Tags: mc, panel

There is the ScreenList functionality bound by default to Alt-Prime (`) in the default mc.keymap:

```
ScreenList = alt-prime
```

Pressing the combination displays "Screens" dialog, which says "Panels" in the actual listing.

How to add panels or screens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the section "Screen selector" in mc's manual. It mentions the three relevant shortcuts: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>.

Viewers and editors open their screens. E.g. press <kbd>F3</kbd> to view a file, and instead of quitting by the usual <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Q</kbd>, try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>.

It looks as if you've quit, but not, you've just temporarily switched back to the main screen. By using the shortcuts mentioned above, you can get back to the viewer, at the position where you left it.

You can have as many viewers and editors open at a time as you wish, however, you can't have multiple file managers.